# Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (4,) when using OpenAI Gym in Jupyter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter-notebook, openai-gym

I have a following code:

```
def get_discrete_state(state): #We have to change the box type into discrete type to manipulate it
    discrete_state = state/step_size + np.array([15,10,1,10])
    return tuple(discrete_state.astype(np.int))

#iterate through our epochs
for epoch in range(epochs + 1): 
    #set the initial time, so we can calculate how much each action takes
    t_initial = time.time() 
    
    #get the discrete state for the restarted environment, so we know what's going on
    discrete_state = get_discrete_state(env.reset()) 
    
    #we create a boolean that will tell us whether our game is running or not
    done = False
    
    #our reward is intialized at zero at the beginning of every eisode
    epoch_reward = 0 

    #Every 1000 epochs we have an episode
    if epoch % 1000 == 0: 
        print("Episode: " + str(epoch))

    while not done: 
        #Now we are in our gameloop
        #if some random number is greater than epsilon, then we take the best possible action we have explored so far
        if np.random.random() > epsilon:

            action = np.argmax(q_table[discrete_state])
        
        #else, we will explore and take a random action
        else:

            action = np.random.randint(0, env.action_space.n) 

        #now we will intialize our new_state, reward, and done variables
        new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action) 
    
        epoch_reward += reward 
        
        #we discretize our new state
        new_discrete_state = get_discrete_state(new_state)
        
        #we render our environment after 2000 steps
        if epoch % 2000 == 0: 
            env.render()

        #if the game loop is still running update the q-table
        if not done:
            max_new_q = np.max(q_table[new_discrete_state])

            current_q = q_table[discrete_state + (action,)]

            new_q = (1 - lr) * current_q + lr * (reward + gamma* max_new_q)

            q_table[discrete_state + (action,)] = new_q

        discrete_state = new_discrete_state
    # if our epsilon is greater than .05m , and if our reward is greater than the previous and if we reached past our 10000 epoch, we recalculate episilon
    
    if epsilon > 0.05: 
        if epoch_reward > prev_reward and epoch > 10000:
            epsilon = math.pow(epsilon_decay_value, epoch - 10000)

            if epoch % 500 == 0:
                print("Epsilon: " + str(epsilon))

    #we calculate the final time
    tfinal = time.time() 
    
    #total epoch time
    episode_total = tfinal - t_initial 
    total_time += episode_total
    
    #calculate and update rewards
    total_reward += epoch_reward
    prev_reward = epoch_reward

    #every 1000 episodes print the average time and the average reward
    if epoch % 1000 == 0: 
        mean = total_time / 1000
        print("Time Average: " + str(mean))
        total_time = 0

        mean_reward = total_reward / 1000
        print("Mean Reward: " + str(mean_reward))
        total_reward = 0

env.close()
```

If I try to run it, I first get:

```
/var/folders/6l/gfqkwfbd7rs176sshdhfz5f80000gn/T/ipykernel_74362/3082769315.py:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  discrete_state = state/step_size + np.array([15,10,1,10])
```

And after that:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [17], in <cell line: 2>()
      4 t_initial = time.time() 
      6 #get the discrete state for the restarted environment, so we know what's going on
----> 7 discrete_state = get_discrete_state(env.reset()) 
      9 #we create a boolean that will tell us whether our game is running or not
     10 done = False

Input In [16], in get_discrete_state(state)
      1 def get_discrete_state(state): #We have to change the box type into discrete type to manipulate it
----> 2     discrete_state = state/step_size + np.array([15,10,1,10])
      3     return tuple(discrete_state.astype(np.int))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (4,)
```

So why does this happen, how can I fix it and make my code work? The code example should work just fine as it is, but for me it doesn't.

BONUS: Also seems like many OpenAI code examples don't work as they exist in different tutorial sources anymore; why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: looks like your `state` or `stepsize` variables have the wrong shape

Comment: Well, it's the exact same code as used in a tutorial video and there it works perfectly fine. Code in GitHub was this one: https://github.com/NoamYakarOfficial/CartPole/blob/main/CartPoleFinal.ipynb